# Table of widgets in Python with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to put a table into a Label Frame in GUI with using Tkinter under python
the table will not contents only static data but also widgets like Buttons, Input Entries, Check Buttons ... etc

for example:

Table 1:

```
[ Nr. | Name | Active |  Action  ]
----------------------------------
[ 1   |  ST  |  [x]   | [Delete] ]
[ 2   |  SO  |  [ ]   | [Delete] ]
[ 3   |  SX  |  [x]   | [Delete] ]
```

`[x]` is a Check Button and `[Delete]` is a Button

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `grid` geometry manager in a frame to layout the widgets however you want. Here's a simple example:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import time

class Example(tk.LabelFrame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.LabelFrame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        data = [
            # Nr. Name  Active
            [1,   "ST", True],
            [2,   "SO", False],
            [3,   "SX", True],
            ]

        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        tk.Label(self, text="Nr.", anchor="w").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ew")
        tk.Label(self, text="Name", anchor="w").grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ew")
        tk.Label(self, text="Active", anchor="w").grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="ew")
        tk.Label(self, text="Action", anchor="w").grid(row=0, column=3, sticky="ew")

        row = 1
        for (nr, name, active) in data:
            nr_label = tk.Label(self, text=str(nr), anchor="w")
            name_label = tk.Label(self, text=name, anchor="w")
            action_button = tk.Button(self, text="Delete", command=lambda nr=nr: self.delete(nr))
            active_cb = tk.Checkbutton(self, onvalue=True, offvalue=False)
            if active:
                active_cb.select()
            else:
                active_cb.deselect()

            nr_label.grid(row=row, column=0, sticky="ew")
            name_label.grid(row=row, column=1, sticky="ew")
            active_cb.grid(row=row, column=2, sticky="ew")
            action_button.grid(row=row, column=3, sticky="ew")

            row += 1

    def delete(self, nr):
        print "deleting...nr=", nr

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root, text="Hello").pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=10, pady=10)
    root.mainloop()
```